# Understanding .NET CIL array initialization code using <PrivateImplementationDetails> and hasfieldrva

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to rewrite a small legacy application for which the source-code is not available anymore.

Having dissembled the code with IDA, I've come across the following CIL, which is used to create and initialize a byte array of length 16:

```
ldc.i4.s 0x10
newarr   [mscorlib]System.Byte
dup
ldtoken  valuetype __StaticArrayInitTypeSize=16 <PrivateImplementationDetails>::'1FE209881344DB101FDBBF280BC13B2AA4C8CFCA'
call     void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::InitializeArray(class [mscorlib]System.Array, valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeFieldHandle)
```

I don't understand the initialization, i.e. what value the array is initialized with. Looking up `<PrivateImplementationDetails>::'1FE209881344DB101FDBBF280BC13B2AA4C8CFCA'` leads to the following CIL:

```
.class private auto sealed ansi <PrivateImplementationDetails> extends [mscorlib]System.Object
                                        // DATA XREF: WindowsService.Program__DecryptFile+9↑o
                                        // WindowsService.Program__DecryptFileToFile+A↑o
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
   01 00 00 00) // ....
  .field assembly static initonly hasfieldrva valuetype __StaticArrayInitTypeSize=16 '1FE209881344DB101FDBBF280BC13B2AA4C8CFCA' // RVA = 00003E98
}

.class nested private explicit sealed ansi __StaticArrayInitTypeSize=16 extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType
{
    .pack 1
}
```

Can anyone with advanced knowledge of CIL tell what value the array is initialized with? In particular, what does `hasfieldrva` refer to?

Comment: It is just int[] arr = {1, 2, 3}.  Use a better decompiler, ILSpy can do it for example.

Comment: @HansPassant - I was under the impression that IDA is one of the best disassemblers? Also this is disassembly, not decompiled source code, right?

Answer (score 4):

The XML documentation for `FieldAttributes.HasFieldRVA` states (emphasis mine):

> Specifies that the field has a relative virtual address (RVA). **The RVA is the location of the method body in the current image, as an address relative to the start of the image file in which it is located.**

This appears to be a technique for quickly initializing arrays of primitive types into static array fields by putting the array in its in-memory layout at a specific offset into the executable image.

RVA = 00003E98 is telling you what that offset is.  `RuntimeHelpers::InitializeArray` is an `internalcall` method that simply copies the bits over.  <s>A strict disassembler like IDA or ILDASM won't tell you the values.</s>

To get the values, you have at least <s>two</s> three options.

**1. Use a better tool for the job**

IDA seems to be geared more for debugging and native executable disassembly.  Its IL output is similar to that of ILDASM, which is about as low-level as it gets.

ILSpy and similar tools will show the initialization values.  You should be able to just copy the field's declaration and initialization right from the decompilation window.

Take a look at how in .NET 4.7.2, `System.Char`'s type initializer initializes the `categoryForLatin1` field.  The IL view is nearly identical to your example.  The C# view is close to what you would see in source code -- except that the [original source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs) for `System.Char` uses constants.  Decompilers can't know which constant was used in source for each value but with a little research and intuition, you can get there yourself.

In fact, if this is an entirely managed assembly, a tool like this would be far better for the whole reverse-engineering effort because it'll give you C# output.  Translating IL to C# by hand can be fun...until it's not.

**2. Retrieve the field at run-time**

Without running the program itself, you can ask it what the values are.

Create a new console application and add a reference to the executable.  Get the `FieldInfo` object for the field in question and then call `GetValue(null)` on it.  Then iterate over the returned array and output the values, preferably formatted so you can simply copy/paste into your new project.

```
FieldInfo field = typeof(WindowsService.Program.DecryptFileToFile).GetField("<field name>", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
byte[] array = (byte[])field.GetValue(null);

foreach (byte value in array)
{
    Console.Writeline("0x{0:X2}", value);
}
```

*This assumes that I intuited the class structure correctly and that the `DecryptFileToFile` nested type is public.  If it's not, you'll need to do some extra reflection work to get to it.*

<s>**3. Read the executable directly (bonus option)**</s>

<s>You might be able to look at that offset within the file itself and see what those 16 bytes are.  IDA should let you jump to that offset and view the data there.  I don't know IDA but that seems like a reasonably basic facility for any debugger.</s>

<s>Frankly, I'm not fully confident in this option but I felt I would be remiss if I didn't mention it.  If the other two options are not available to you and this yields meaningful data, my hat goes off to you.</s>

**EDIT**: I tried looking at the offset into the file on disk and the data was not there.  It must refer to the offset as loaded into memory.

**NEW 3. ILDASM *does* give you the bytes**

Maybe IDA will, too.  You just have to know where to look.  The `.field` directive will have a label at the end, `at I_xxxxxxxx`.  Here's is `System.Char::categoryForLatin1`:

```
.field static assembly initonly valuetype
    '<PrivateImplementationDetails>'/'__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=256' B53A2C6DF21FC88B17AEFC40EB895B8D63210CDF
    at I_004E49CC
```

Later on in the file, you'll see a `.data` directive with the same label defining the raw bytes:

```
.data cil I_004E49CC = bytearray (
    0E 0E 0E 0E 0E 0E 0E 0E
    // and so on for another 248 bytes
    )
```